# Meta Tags For Individual Pages

Tags: php, meta-tags

I currently have a website based off a PHP template so all pages use the same header.php file via PHP's include.

I am just getting myself into meta data, etc. and wanted to know how I go about having specific meta data for each individual page if each page is using the same header?

Answer (score 2):

This is highly dependent on templating system you use.
f.i. Zend Framework Zend_View enables you with view helpers for such tasks.
If relying on something far less advanced as simple include "header.php", then you can specify a variable before including header file and set it with desired value, while in included file echo that variable.

Something like this:

index.php

```
<?php
//...
$meta_tags = '<meta content="Some description" http-equiv="description" />....';
include 'header.php':
//...
?>
```

header.php

```
...
<link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<?php echo $meta_tags ?>
...
```

Comment: Yes, I'm just using a simple custom template that I created for this small project.. nothing large like Zend, WP or Drupal.

Comment: @HTMLDeveloper this code always works - its so simple it can't fail. you are probably using it wrong. '...' means more code here